# How to add Highcharts on UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, highcharts

I am totally new to HighCharts and I referred example http://blog.li-labs.com/developing-ios-apps-with-custom-charting/ and tried same, but on iPad simulator I am getting a blank screen.

I have referred questions on stack-overflow, but still it is not working. 
Can anyone tell where am I going wrong.

EDIT : Code in My HTML file :

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

        // Radialize the colors
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });

        // Build the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                    ['IE',       26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Chrome',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Safari',    8.5],
                    ['Opera',     6.2],
                    ['Others',   0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<!--<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> How to add and use the Javascript libraries in XCode
>
> Here is a simple view of how I handle the code and data within XCode.
>
> 1. Download the Javascript reporting package from your preferd chart site. In my case: http://www.highcharts.com/download
> 2. Add or import the files into XCode resources. (I suggest creating a group called JS).
> 3. When adding a resource to XCode it will generally be marked as being needed to be compiled. Ensure that the files are not listed as
>      being “Compiled”. The easiest way is to simply drag the files from
>      Targets -> Your Project Name -> Compiled Sources  into Targets -> Your
>      Project Name -> Copy Bundle Resources.
> 4. Create a test html file or simply import one from your HighChart (or any other javascript chart library) examples folder. In my case I
>      name it hcpie.html
> 5. Ensure that any file references in the  tags do not recurse or move into any folder (even if they are in one in your project).
>      e.g.
>
> RIGHT =
>
> WRONG =
>
> 1. Create a UIWebView within Interface Designer and link it to your view (in my case I named it chart1). e.g.
>
> @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController { IBOutlet UIWebView
>   *chart1; }
>
> @end
>
> 1. Simply reference the HTML example file when loading.
>
>    - (void)viewDidLoad {
>
> NSString *pathOfFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”hcpie”
>   ofType:@”html”]; NSString *htmlText = [NSString
>   stringWithContentsOfFile:pathOfFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
>   error:nil];
>
> NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathOfFile];
>
> [chart1 loadHTMLString: htmlText baseURL:baseURL];
>
> [super viewDidLoad];
>
> }

Comment: Highcharts has its iOS wrapper.

Comment: How can we change graph values from our controller and then load it to webview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps:-

1) First just creat one html file and do the needful code or for trial can copy html code from examples that you get from package http://www.highcharts.com/download

2) Make sure that the scripts in html should have proper .js links 
for e.g:- `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`

or

if you want to give it locally you can write `<script src="highcharts.js"></script>`
But make sure that the .js files are there in your application folder.

```
3) NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"graph" ofType:@"html"];
   NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   [obj loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];  // Webview *obj;
```

Hope this help you. In my case its working.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned. Still it is not working. Just check my html file as well.I have edited the question.Still

Comment: write <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 in body part instead of    <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="exporting.js"></script>

Comment: I run your html by changing as per above. And it works.Please let me know is it working for you?

Comment: I am using the same approach but I am not able to render it into the  simulator. However the same file opens perfectly in Safari in Mac. Any clues .?

Comment: `NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"line" ofType:@"htm"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    
    UIWebView *obj = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 650)];
    obj.delegate = self;
    [self.contentView addSubview:obj];  
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    [obj loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];`

Comment: not able to load locally. can anyone please explain how can i load locally?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the suggestions in this post and couldn't get the HighChart load.

The problem ended up being the "loadHTMLString" call.  Passing nil for the baseURL was incorrect.  Here's what worked for me - I needed to pass the actual baseURL:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:url ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but to me its opens perfectly in Safari in Mac, but not working in simulator. Any help.

Comment: `NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"line" ofType:@"htm"]; NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];          UIWebView *obj = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 650)];     obj.delegate = self;     [self.contentView addSubview:obj];       NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];     [obj loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];`

Comment: @BalramTiwari my answer works in the sim, on real devices, etc.  Perhaps you're not copying all your .js resources to the device?  You might want to check your project configuration, specifically the "Copy Bundle Resources" section in the Build Phases tab of your project.

Comment: thank you. I have tried it on the simulator only. Let me try it on real device. I will update further.

Answer (score 0):

**Useful code for calling .html in UIWebView.**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
   {
     NSString *pathOfFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"chart" ofType:@"html"]; 

     NSString *htmlText =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathOfFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

     NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathOfFile];

    [UIWebView loadHTMLString: htmlText baseURL:baseURL];
   }
```