# HighChart Libraries for Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, highcharts

I want to use HighCharts in Android and iOS mobile apps .
Is there any libraries or Gradle dependencies are availble in Android or iOS?

Comment: Asking for Libraries, SDKs, Tutorials and other off-site resources is off-topic on Stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Is high charts for android wrapper found in bintray  an opensource ?

Answer (score 5):

If you have already written code in `Highcharts` and want to display it in `iOS`, then the best way would be to display the chart inside a `webView`. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16332563/3894781):

> 1) First just creat one html file and do the needful code or for trial can copy html code from examples that you get from package http://www.highcharts.com/download
>
> 2) Make sure that the scripts in html should have proper .js links for e.g:-
>
> or
>
> if you want to give it locally you can write  But make sure that the .js files are there in your application folder.
>
> 3) `NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"graph" ofType:@"html"];
>    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
>    [obj loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];`

**OR**

You could use one of the many native libraries available for android and iOS. "*Why would I want to do that*" you ask? Well, for starters, Native code performs much smoother and faster than *HTML/Javascript-code-inside-a-webview*. Additionally, you would have much finer control of what you display. For instance, you could handle [Clustering](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView#performance) inside your app itself.

Here are some of the good ones I know, but there are lots of good libraries if you search.

**Android** : [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

**iOS** : [iOS-Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) and [JBChartView](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView)

Answer (score 2):

You may check the following libraries

- iOS
  : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swiftcharts
- Android:
  https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart