# Using Highcharts JS in native mobile application

Tags: android, highcharts, angular, nativescript

so i started to look into building android application that would mirror some stuff i use on a webpage. Namely weather meteograms that are built with Highcharts.

Since i am using angular 2 i thought it would be logical to go angular 2 + nativeScript way. And i cant seem easilly find information about using Highcharts within native application.

Does anyone has examples or knows some page with information about this subject.

Worst case - what would be a good alternative to highcharts to use in mobile app built with angular2 and NativeScript?

Please dont suggest paid librarys/packages.

Comment: I think that you can look for an answer in this SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349060/highchart-libraries-for-android-and-ios

Comment: in my opinion you could use `nativescript-telerik-ui-pro` plugin. You could use his chart component. I could also review this article here- http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/Chart/overview

Comment: First sugestion has pure native implementation (as far as i could understand) and i am not familiar with that (i am good with javascript and angular2).

As for the second one looks interesting but not sure if its gonna be able to handle complex charts with dynamic data changes (thats why i am using Highcharts as it has clear API not to mention its JS so easy to expand functionality). Gonna read it on telerik a bit more though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a WebView to the XML file and load a local HTML containing the charts.

Comment: can i control its contents same way as in webpage? (being able to catch events mostly)

Comment: Maybe this will help https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface

Comment: thanks that looks promising. will try as soon i get chance and if all is good for me i will set this as answer (so far its the closest thing to answer i was looking for anyway)

Comment: managed to make it work, Had some problems with android emulator not reloading app as expected. But once i cought that problem all goes smoothly. Thanks for a great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid plugin for creating charts in nativeScript aclled telerik-ui-pro.
More about it [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/Chart/overview)

Demonstration application can be found [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular)

Comment: i will edit my question to include that its preferred free :) paid is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

high charts uses the DOM to generate the charts, nativescript doesn't use the DOM for rendering so is a no go..

i was able to generate a bar chart (on android) by creating a small plugin out of this android library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: Hmm it seems i will have to look into how to use it inside NativeScript. Or start thinking if its possible to wrap my current code into something. I think its called hybrid app.

Comment: He could still display a WebView with a simple page containing the charts